# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: dxa, powershell, installation, iis-and-asp.net

I am installing the reference implementation. after running the web application powershell script i am unable to open the page. the page says HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error.
Detailed Error Information:
Module CustomErrorModule
Notification SendResponse
Handler ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0
Error Code 0x80070021
Config Error This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".
Config File \?\D:\APPS\Tridion\DataStore\web.config
Requested URL http://localhost:81/
Physical Path D:\APPS\Tridion\DataStore
Logon Method Not yet determined
Logon User Not yet determined
Config Source:
29:< httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingesponse="PassThrough"/>
30:< staticContent>
31:< remove fileExtension=".json"/>

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is Tridion or DXA specific. Some Googling suggests that your IIS server is not configured for application development and is locking the ability to over-ride configuration.

See [this](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/how-to-use-locking-in-iis-configuration) page for an explanation of the feature and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794985/iis-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path-configuration-lock) Stack Overflow question for some possible resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

I just changed the web.config file in the root folder to comment out  tag. and that fixed my problem. Thank you a lot for the help.